# virtual machine internet connection

Tags: vmware-workstation

i am using vmware workstation ace edition. i have rhl 9 as my guest os and windows xp as my host os. i have a wifi connection at home that i use to connect to the internet, using my host os.

i would like to get connected to the internet using my guest os running on vmware. i googled out for the solution and all i could find was to do a nat connection between my guest and host os. but this did not seem to work. perhaps there's something i m not doing correctly or am missing out altogether.

on the ethernet card's icon in my vmware i get some options. they are :-
bridged 
nat 
host only
custom

i tried selecting each one but none worked out.

as of my guest os ..the ip that i have set through netconfig is 192.168.0.3 and that of my host os that i have set is 192.168.0.1. so the host and the guest communicate pretty well when i select the host only option. As of my wifi connection configuration, it is configured to obtain ip address and dns address automatically. But when i connect to the internet through my wifi it does not work for my guest os.
plzzzzzzzzz help

Comment: make sure you select the wifi connection not the ethernet in NAT !!

Comment: thanx for ur reply....but could you please explain how to do this.